# Image is not aligning to bottom right in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I want the image that you are seeing on the right side to be on the right bottom.
It is currently in the right center.

I used `Alignment: Alignment.bottomRight` but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]

```
                                        Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[  
                                            Expanded(                                        
                                              child: ListView.builder
                                              (
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                                itemCount: list3.length,

                                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) 
                                                {
                                                  return new ListView
                                                            (
                                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                              children: <Widget>
                                                              [                                                       
                                                                ListTile(
                                                                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                                                                              radius: 6.0,
                                                                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                                                            ),
                                                                    title : Text(list3[Index], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25,),)
                                                                ),
                                                              ]
                                                            );
                                                },                                          
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            
                                            Expanded(
                                                  child: 
                                                    GestureDetector(
                                                      child: Image(
                                                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                                              image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
                                                              height: 15,
                                                              width: 15,
                                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                            ),
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,` of `Row`will do the trick.

[image]

Does it solve your question?

Comment: This is not next to 'item3' in your image also. It is below it. Please put it next to 'item3' on that same horizontal plane.

Comment: are you using Column for parent widget? And can you add an image that you like to archive?

Comment: This Row is inside a ListView

Comment: The main space is effecting from `ListView` that is inside `ListView.builder`, and while we are wrapping with `Expanded` both root Row level widget it is taking the half screen width. Also, i replaced `ListView` with `Column` and `ListTile with Row just to check`. Here is my observation. Instead of providing `Expanded` on `Row> ListView.builder` we can use Fixed width . also main row  will have `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,`, i maybe changed others things too during the process.